# CRM 2013: Passing Account Info into Webservice via Plugin

Tags: web-services, plugins, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We are using CRM 2013. I'm trying to create a plugin that triggers when a CRM Account is created. Then the plugin will fires and sends an attribute 'AccountNumber' into an internal webservice. However the webservice does not seem to get called whatsoever now.

At first I thought I had to do a PostImage, but then decided not to use it anymore. Also at first I was using "EntityMoniker" as a plugin parameter but then corrected it to type "Target".

Here's my code:

Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

```
var targetEntity = context.GetParameterCollection<Entity>(context.InputParameters, 
                                                          "Target");

if (targetEntity == null)
  {throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, 
                                            "Target Entity cannot be null");}

// Make sure the new Account Id is available
if (!context.OutputParameters.Contains("id"))
  {return;}

var accountID = new Guid(context.OutputParameters["id"].ToString());

//putting postImage here but not being used
var postImage = context.PostEntityImages["PostImage"];

if (postImage == null)
  {throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(OperationStatus.Failed, 
                                            "Post Image is required");}

var AccountNumber = context.OutputParameters["new_AccountNumber"].ToString();
var service = new ServiceClient("");
var newProp = new PropertySetup
{
  _prop = new Property
  {
    _propertyNm = AccountNumber
  }
};

service.CreateNewProperty(newProp);
service.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the new_AccountNumber attribute change:

```
var AccountNumber = context.OutputParameters["new_AccountNumber"].ToString();
```

to

```
var AccountNumber = targetEntity.Attributes["new_AccountNumber"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it, however I still don't see any webservice call. Is there a way to check whether a plugin gets fired? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to check whether a plugin gets fired. You can simply throw an exception or you can debug your plugin: http://inogic.com/blog/2012/06/how-to-debug-plugins-using-profiler/